# Uploading multiple image to web API

Tags: android, file-upload, for-loop, http-post

Hello guys can you help me with this one? I am currently making an application that could upload multiple files into the web API, currently, I can upload a single file but when I am trying to upload multiple files only the first file uploaded successfully and not corrupted, although the other files(filename) can be still seen to the website but corrupted. I have a strange doubt that my codes below (specially the loop) gives incorrect output on my application but I cannot figure it out. Thanks in advance for anyone who could help me.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) 
{

    try 
        {

            JSONObject jObjectFileUpload = new JSONObject();

            FileBody localFileBody;
            MultipartEntity localMultipartEntity;

            HttpParams httpParameters            = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
            HttpPost httpPost                    = new HttpPost("http://sampleserversvr4.guru.com:0727/api/fileupload");
            HttpClient httpclient                = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            httpPost.addHeader("Authorization","Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString((_username + ":" + _password).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));

            for (int i = 0; i < Constants.ARRAYLIST_URI.size(); i++) 
            {
                uri = Constants.ARRAYLIST_URI.get(i);
                file = new File(uri);
                mimetype = Constants.getMimeType(uri);
                filename = file.getName();
                localFileBody = new FileBody(file, mimetype);
                localMultipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                try {
                    localMultipartEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody(filename));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    localMultipartEntity.addPart("chunk", new StringBody("1"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                localMultipartEntity.addPart("file data", localFileBody);
                httpPost.setEntity(localMultipartEntity);
                HttpResponse localHttpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                Log.i("response upload", localHttpResponse.toString());
                Log.i("Multipart Entity", localMultipartEntity.toString());
            }




        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("fileUpload", "ClientProtocolException in callWebService(). " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("fileUpload","IOException in callWebService(). " + e.getMessage());
                }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of HttpPost  , you may have just one post change. So that in your for loop you will set new your HttpPost and HttpClient. Create your HttpPost and HttpClient instance in your for loop, then try it again.